# Cant access my flask python program on a different server

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, server

So I asked a few days ago how to run a program from a browser on a different server and someone told me about Flask and I tought I should`ve gave it a try

And that s what I did: I wrote the program

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/addnew', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def send():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']

        return render_template('see.html', name=name)
    return render_template('index.html')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I made up the most basic form in html so i can at least try the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Pls work</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="/addnew">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="name"><br>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I run it from the console (activating venv and all that), but when i go to 'link/addnew' it tells me the page does not exist

In the putty console tells me it runs on 0.0.0.0

I tryed to put the host on 127.0.0.1:5000 but it doesnt also doesnt work

I am really a noobie in this so I try to copy and understand as much as possible, but i dont understand where the problem stands, please help

Comment: use `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)` and put the stacktraces here

Comment: Is your app and the browser on the same system?

Comment: make sure your firewalls allows connections. `ufw allow 80`

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu use this command to allow traffic to your server on the port 5000:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5000 -j ACCEPT
```

If that does not work please share your debug logs.